# react-google-maps does not work

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs

I am building this weather application. Everything seems to work, but I cannot make google maps to work. I saw that API key is needed, I imported it. Then followed the documentation of react-google-maps while installing it in my project, but it still does not work, however, I have no errors in my console anymore.

Can you please look at it, what is wrong here? Feel free to clone it.
https://github.com/garstikaitis/weather-app/blob/master/src/components/google_map.js

http://arsti.net/weather-app/

Comment: I'd guess that your '100%' height is '100%' of zero. Try using a fixed value like '300px' to see if that shows the map.

Comment: @RyanH. ! I don't know about Gintaras' case, but your guess solved mine! :D
Write your guess as an answer and I will upvote it :)

Comment: Hi @Seigo. Glad to hear that this helped you. I've written up a (more detailed) answer as you suggested. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 2):

For the specific app referenced in the question, I am able to see the map when I run the app locally. However, it is very, very narrow. This does not seem to be a react-google-maps issue but rather an HTML table layout issue in which the width of the map needs to be adjusted.

On another note, a common issue, if you don't see any map at all, could be due to setting the `height` of the map to `"100%"`. You'd be asking for 100% of the height of the parent container, which could easily be a collapsed `div` of zero height, so you'd be essentially asking for 100% of nothing.

Here's an example using the @next version of [react-google-maps](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/) (currently 7.0.0 as I write this) and React 15.6.1:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap } from "react-google-maps";
import withScriptjs from "react-google-maps/lib/async/withScriptjs";

const GettingStartedGoogleMap = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(props => (
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={3}
    defaultCenter={{ lat: -25.363882, lng: 131.044922 }}
  />
)));

ReactDOM.render(
  <div style={{ height: '600px' }}>
    <GettingStartedGoogleMap
      googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.28"
      loadingElement={<div></div>}
      containerElement={ <div style={{ height: `100%` }} /> }
      mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
    />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

If you removed the outer `div`'s fixed height of `600px` or replaced it with `100%` the `div` would collapse and you wouldn't see the map at all. Hope this helps.

Comment: I like the detailed response. Do you perhaps have an example project in react using Google Maps services like Places? Cheers!

Comment: I haven't had a chance to use the Places library yet :(